# С++ Сортировка Двумерного массива по строчно

Tags: c++

Задача: Двумерный массив. Целочисленный. Клавиатура. Всё через уазатели: Сортировать каждую строку в массиве чередуя по убыванию и по возрастанию. Т.е. первая строчка отсортирована по убыванию, вторая по возрастания, третья снова по убыванию, четвертая по возрастанию и т.д.

Не могу реализовать сортировку каждой строки двумерного массива.

Вот мой пример кода

```
srand(time(NULL));
int row = 3;
int colm = 5;
int swap = 0;
int** numbers = new int* [row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    numbers[i] = new int[colm];
}
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colm; j++) {
        numbers[i][j] = (int)rand() % 10;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colm; j++) {
        cout << " " << numbers[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Используйте `std::sort`

Comment: Здесь одно из неоговоренных условий что реализовать надо путем сортировки "Пузырьком" но у меня не хватает опыта и знания как это сделать для двумерного массива и соблюдения условия задания выше.

Comment: @Fred, Функции проходили? Реализуйте функцию сортировки для одномерного массива и затем в цикле пройдитесь по строкам.

Comment: @MaximTimakov нет, не проходили

Answer (score 0):

Ну как то так напишите - максимальн просто

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int GenRandomUInt(unsigned int l_bound, unsigned int h_bound) {  
  static std::random_device r_dev{};
  static std::mt19937_64 mt_engine(r_dev());
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<> u_int_d(l_bound, h_bound);

  return static_cast<unsigned int>(u_int_d(mt_engine));
}

void FreeMultiArray(unsigned int** array, const unsigned int size) {
  if (array == nullptr || size == 0) {
    return;
  }
  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
    if (array[i] != nullptr) {
      delete[] array[i];
    }
  }
  if (array != nullptr) {
    delete[] array;
  }
}

void FillRandom(unsigned int* array, const unsigned int size) {
  if (0 == size || array == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
    array[i] = GenRandomUInt(0, 100);
  }
}

unsigned int** GenMultiArray(const unsigned int size) {
  if (0 == size) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  unsigned int** array = new unsigned int*[size];
  if (array == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
    array[i] = new unsigned int[size];
    if (array[i] == nullptr) {
      FreeMultiArray(array, size);
      return nullptr;
    }
    FillRandom(array[i], size);    
  }

  return array;
}

void PrintMultiArray(unsigned int** array, const unsigned int h_size, const unsigned int v_size) {
  if (array == nullptr || h_size == 0 || v_size == 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < v_size; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == nullptr) {
      return;
    }
  }

  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < v_size; ++i) {
    for (unsigned int j{0}; j < h_size; ++j) {
      std::cout << array[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  const unsigned int size = 10;
  unsigned int** array = GenMultiArray(size);
  if (array == nullptr) {
    return 1;
  }

  for (unsigned int i{0}; i < size; ++i) {
    if (i % 2) {
      std::sort(&array[i][0], &array[i][0] + size, std::greater<unsigned int>()); 
    } else {
      std::sort(&array[i][0], &array[i][0] + size, std::less<unsigned int>()); 
    }
  }
  PrintMultiArray(array, size, size);
  FreeMultiArray(array, size);

  return 0;
}
```